# How connect only localhost to MySQL in Loopback 4?

Tags: mysql, loopback, loopback4

I can't connect to MySQL database via 127.0.0.1. My provider says could connect via localhost.
In mysql.datasource.config.json writed localhost, but loopback try connect to 127.0.0.1.
How connect only to localhost? Version loopback: 4

Answer (score 0):

Datasource.json

`"datsourceName": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "database": "databse_name",
    "password": "password",
    "name": "datsourceName",
    "user": "root",
    "connector": "mysql"
  },`

config.json

```
"restApiRoot": "/api",
 "host": "0.0.0.0",
 "port": 3000
```